# Protecting my iCalendar

Tags: c#, .net, icalendar

I have my own application with a calendar.  Everyday I export the data to an iCalendar (ics) file.  This ics file is on my webserver and I can successfully import into my Outlook.  My question is, what stops from anyone else connecting my calendar?  Is there a way to protect it, so that Outlook asks for a login and password before importint this web calendar?

Comment: Hi there welcome to SO. Please make sure to tell us what language your application is written in and a sense for how it works. If you are downloading ics files from your app can you just password protect that endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply HTTP Authentication on the directory where the calendar is hosted. If you're using Apache, see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html.

Do note that it seems to have problems on Outlook 2007. Other clients like Thunderbird+Lightning can import the http password protected ics file properly, but Outlook 2007 doesn't recognize it as a valid ics file. (I'm stuck at this problem right now, so if anyone can help me find a solution, I'd be grateful.)